# Importing photos to Raspberry Pi from a smart phone using Python

Tags: python, import, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to import photos from my smartphone to a folder on my Raspberry Pi using a Python script. My script looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import glob
import shutil

source = "mtp://[usb:001,014]/"

folders = [
    "/Phone/Pictures/Ballons/",
    "/Phone/Pictures/Familie/",
    "/Phone/Pictures/Florida/",
    "/Phone/Pictures/Ramona/",
    "/Phone/Pictures/Screenshots/",
]
dest = "/home/pi/Desktop/Photos/"

for dir in folders:
    if not os.path.exists(dir):
        continue
    print ("checking %s") % dir
    for file in glob.glob(source + dir + "*.jpg"):
        print ("copy file %s to %s") % (file, dest)
        shutil.copy(file, dest)
```

When I run it, even though no error messages are displayed, pictures are not imported to Raspberry Pi.

What is wrong with my script?

Comment: I'd guess that the issue is with the `source` part of your filename. I doubt that `glob` can handle it, since it looks more like a URL than a file system path. If `glob` doesn't find anything, your code will do nothing.

Comment: Hm, I also tried 'source = "/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A001%2C014%5D/"', but it didn't do it either.

Comment: Where did you get this ` "mtp://[usb:001,014]/"`? After connect you must`mount` your `/def/usb` to some mount point in your file system, e..g. `/mnt/phone`.